# Determine the interface used for a union interface

Tags: typescript, interface, arrow-functions, generic-type-argument, union-types

Suppose I have the following:

```
interface StringOp {
    (a: string, b: string): string;
}
interface NumberOp {
    (a: number, b: number): number;
}
function doThing(callback: StringOp | NumberOp) {
    if (callback is StringOp) {
        callback("a", "b");
    } else {
        callback(1, 2);
    }
}
```

How can I actually express `callback is StringOp` as a type-check?

---

I tried to simplify the above as an MWE, but below closer to my actual use-case:

```
interface TickFunction<T> {
  (val: T): void;
}
interface IndexedTickFunction<T> {
  (val: T, index: number): void;
}
function forEachTick<T>(callback: TickFunction<T> | IndexedTickFunction<T>) {
  ...
}
```

If possible, I'd like to keep calling `forEachTick` using arrow-notation literals:

- `forEachTick<SomeType>((v) => { ... })` or
- `forEachTick<SomeType>((v,i) => { ... })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TS interfaces exist only during development process so there is no way to check interface type in runtime and do smth. So you have to somehow include an "indicator" to your interface in order to set it with some value when you create your callback methods. This indicator can be used to check callback type in runtime. TS also provides [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) so the final solution will look like:

```
interface StringOp {
    opType: 'StringOp',
    (a: string, b: string): string;
}
interface NumberOp {
    opType: 'NumberOp',
    (a: number, b: number): number;
}

function isStringOp(op: StringOp | NumberOp): op is StringOp {
    return op.opType === 'StringOp';
}

function doThing(callback: StringOp | NumberOp) {
    if (isStringOp(callback)) {
        callback("a", "b");
    } else {
        callback(1, 2);
    }
}
```

---

I've added another example according to the updated question:

```
interface TickFunction<T> {
  (val: T): void;
}
interface IndexedTickFunction<T> {
  (val: T, index: number): void;
}

function isTickFn<T>(fn: TickFunction<T> | IndexedTickFunction<T>): fn is TickFunction<T> {
    // in your example the indicator might be the function length
    // because it indicates the number of arguments expected by the function
    return fn.length === 1;
}

// I guess you also have to pass arguments to this function in order to pass them to your callback methods
function forEachTick<T>(callback: TickFunction<T> | IndexedTickFunction<T>, value: T, index?: number) {
  if (isTickFn(callback)) {
    callback(value);
  } else {
    callback(value, index);
  }
}

for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  forEachTick<string>((v: string) => console.log(v), 'some text');
}
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  forEachTick<boolean>((v: boolean, index: number) => console.log(v, index), true, i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't imagine how TypeScript would actually compile an interface into JS -- it definitely feels like just a type-checking tool. Could this 'indicator' be used when the overloaded function is intended to take a function literal using arrow notation? (See edit for an example closer to my use case; it seems I over-generalized.)

Comment: Sure. In your final example the `length` of function arguments can be used as an indicator to determine function type in runtime. For more details - see the updated answer.

Comment: Sweet. If I had functions of the same length, though, is there a way to inline the indicator?

Comment: This is a tricky one :) In this case you have to create callbacks based on interface with 'indicator' field, like this one `interface TickFunction1 { (val: number): void; type: fnTypes; }`. I've created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fcfzld?file=index.ts) for this case. In TS there are also another different ways to check the interface type at runtime (for more details check [this article](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) )